# Why is my output wrong in this code?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that shows how many people use a specific e-mail provider based on user input. I have a CSV file and every time I run the program it prints `0`.

My code is as follows:

```
user = input('Enter an email'):
c=0
f_in = open('us-500.csv','r')
f_in.readline()
for line in f_in:
    line = line.strip(' ')
    first, last, company, address, city, country, state, zip, phone1, phone2, email, web = line.split(',')
    for count in email:
            if count == user:
                c +=1
print(c) 
f_in.close()
```

Comment: Do instead `user = int(input('Enter an email:'))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking to match the domain - `@example.com` - in various email addresses. Is this correct?

If so, you will have to expect the email to look like a typical address, "user@example.com", and break the address into pieces first.

Try this:

```
user, domain = email.split('@', 1)
```

At this point, the `domain` will be something like "example.com", which might be enough for you.

```
provider = input('Enter an email provider (like "gmail.com"): '):

count = 0
with open('us-500.csv', 'r') as users:
    users.readline()   # skip header lines
    for user in users:
        first, last, company, address, city, country, state, zip, phone1, phone2, email, web = user.split(',')
        _, domain = email.split('@', 1)
        if domain == provider:
            count += 1

print("Email provider '{}' has {} users".format(provider, count))
```